# How to get Web content from web server to android application

Tags: android

I am doing a project in android, to get the website data's into my android application.
I tried JSON but it doesn't help me to achieve my project. Please help me...

Comment: Use Ksoap as web service .

Comment: Thank you friend... but it only get wsdl formate.

Comment: please provide a sample of input data, maybe we could advise you an approach.

Answer (score 0):

i've used this code for my project

```
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        String getURL = "http://yourservername/wifi.ashx?cmd=get;1;";
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(getURL);
        HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);
        HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();
        String str;

        if (resEntityGet != null) {
            str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet).substring(2, 4); // determined the maximumum id in server
            str.lastIndexOf(str);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
//      link.setText("errorororo");
    }
```